# UnModified fields are not getting WebAPI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am working in webapi. I have one update method to perform modification. There are number of properties but i only wants to update few fields.

So i just skipped the unwanted fields using entry.Property(propertyName).IsModified = false; in data layer. All my logic working fine but after update, when i got the new update entry, it didn't have the fields which are not updated

**My Controller Code:**

```
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(int id, MyModel model)
    {
        model.Id = id;
        bool result = await _modelLogic.UpdateData(item);
        if (!result)
        {
            return BadRequest("Could not Save to the database");
        }
        return await GetModel(item.Id);
    }

    [Route("{id:int}", Name = "GetModelById")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetModel(int id)
    {
        MyModel model = await _modelLogic.GetModelAsync(id);
        if (Model == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(model);
    }
```

**My Business Logic:**

```
    public async Task<bool> UpdateData(MyModel model)
    {
        model.RecordStatus = DataStatus.Active;
        string[] excludedProperties = new[] {"RegistrationId", "StartDate", "ProtocolType", "Code" };
        _repo.Update(model, excludedProperties);
        bool status = await _repo.SaveAsync();
        return status;
    }
```

Here RegistrationId is a foreign key.

**My Data Code:**

```
    public void Update(MyModel model, string[] excludedProperties)
    {
        excludedPropertiesInUpdate = excludedPropertiesInUpdate.Union(excludedProperties).ToArray();
        base.Update(model);
    }
```

**My Generic Repository / base repository**

```
    internal string[] excludedPropertiesInUpdate = new[] { "CreatedDate", "CreatedBy" };
    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        entity.UpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
       entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

        //Restrict Modification for Specified Properties
        foreach(string propertyName in excludedPropertiesInUpdate)
        {
            entry.Property(propertyName).IsModified = false;   
        }
    }
```

Like i told, all logic working fine. But when it shows the response, the fields which are not updated shown as null. eg: RegistrationId, Code etc. But in database its there not updated anything

Comment: I don't recommend passing entities out to the view, rather use a view model and then when you pass that view model back to the domain (repository) retrieve the current entity and update the fields that you want.  In your example what were the values of these #null fields in the Model that you passed to the repository? It almost sounds like it might be a case where the model sent to the repository was incomplete, you attached it to the context, set it to "Modified", ignored some properties, but expected values from the DB to populate the attached entity? (entry)

Comment: @StevePy thanks. i already used viewmodel only.The properties which are not passed (marked as not modified) are return as null But in db values are there not updated. I also did the same way you told by taking existing object and update the properties while updaing. i that case i got some error like you have another context with same primary key

Comment: Look like you should map some properties as [computed or identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You only store new values in database, but do not load unmodified properties to entity.

```
internal string[] excludedPropertiesInUpdate = new[] { "CreatedDate", "CreatedBy" };
public void Update(T entity)
{
    entity.UpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
   entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

    //Restrict Modification for Specified Properties
    foreach(string propertyName in excludedPropertiesInUpdate)
    {
        entry.Property(propertyName).IsModified = false;   
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();

    //load actual values from the database.
    entry.Reload(); 
}
```

Comment: This will reload the actual values an set the state as unchanged. So update will not happen

Comment: You are right! `SaveChanges()` should be placed before calling `Reload()`. Or getting actual value after updating model in the database. I've updated my answer.

Comment: but here i am not including save changes here. its different method. But if you see the code in api, the get method already called after update happened

Comment: There is context in EF. You can think it is like cache. Your `get` function reads data data from context NOT from DB (that is why some properties are null) to read actual data you should call `reload` function. You can do it in `get` method.

Comment: got it. Thanks. Actually i do like create separate method  as notrackable to get the base so context not saved and working fine